# VBA Access more than 2 CreateParameter

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I need to create an Access program but I am having trouble.
Here is the problem. 
When I type information as below picture, all of the information should be inserted to the Listbox. 'BlendID' and 'Blend Method' are same for all element and only 'Precursor's' information change. So when I typed two item of precursor, there need to be two rows but I only get 1 data in the list box. 
(Precursor2's information should be inserted in listbox but it is not working now)
[image]

Here is my code

```
Private Sub AddToListBlend_Click()

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strConn As String

Dim par As ADODB.Parameter           'input
'Dim introw As Integer
'On Error GoTo errorhandle
'introw = ListBlend.ListIndex + 1

strConn = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=CHU-AS-0004;DATABASE=RTC_LaplaceD_DEV;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn               'open connection

If IsNull(TextRequestNo.value) Or TextRequestNo.value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please select Request No first")

Else

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.AddBlendPrac"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

    Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@BlendID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextB10.value)
    cmd.parameters.Append par
    Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@BlendMethod", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextB11.value)
    cmd.parameters.Append par
    Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@RequestID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextRequestNo.value)
    cmd.parameters.Append par
    Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@SampleID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextB12.value)
    cmd.parameters.Append par
    Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@WLocation", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, WLocation1.value)
    cmd.parameters.Append par
    cmd.Execute

conn.Close 'close connection
Set conn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing

MsgBox "Succeeded"
List731.Requery

End If
End Sub
```

I am aware that I need to add Precursor2's information but I do not know how to do it. As you can see first information is inserted to the ListBox, but second one is not.

Would you please share your idea about this?

Comment: what is the data source for the form that is pictured?

Comment: My source code is too long so that I cannot post it in this web page. However, the important source code is included in this page.

Comment: not source code, **data source** ... does your form data come from a table or a query ?

Comment: Yes, my data is linked to ms-sql server.